# Locate nested property with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I have an object model that looks like the below.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class2 @Class2;
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class3 @Class3;
    public Class4 @Class4;
}

public class Class3
{
    public Class5 @Class5;
}

public class Class4
{
    public Class5 @Class5;
}

public class Class5
{
    public Class6 @Class6;
}

public class Class6
{
}
```

Can anyone recommend a way to iterate over the hierarchy until I can get the instance of Class5, which is a property of Class4?  Using .NET 4.5 on VS2012, C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "entry point" is at the "top" of the hierarchy (e.g. `Class1` or `Class2`) I can think of some extension methods which do something similar to the suggested Visitor pattern.

```
public static class FieldAndTypeExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> walk(this Type t) {
        foreach (FieldInfo f in t.GetFields()) {
            foreach (FieldInfo nextField in f.walk()) {
                yield return nextField;
            }
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> walk(this FieldInfo f) {
        yield return f;
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = f.FieldType.GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo nextField in fieldInfos) {
            foreach (FieldInfo anotherNext in nextField.walk()) {
                yield return anotherNext;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A possible usage would be:

```
Type t = typeof(Class1);
var allFieldsFound = from field
                     in t.walk()
                     where field.FieldType == typeof(Class5)
                     select field;
var firstFound = allFieldsFound.FirstOrDefault();
```

Both `firstFound` and the entries in `allFieldsFound` are of type [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8c2tewk.aspx) so you can get the declaring (enclosing) class via its `DeclaringType` property.

Perhaps this is not the most elegant solution but maybe a basic idea to build upon.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way of doing this would be to use a Visitor pattern. In your case your Visit method would use reflection to "crack open" the passed in type.

There is a good [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of how to construct an Expression Tree visitor, which is doing something similar (Hierarchy crawling) to what you want.

Comment: curious as to why you would need this when you know the property path ahead of time...?

Comment: @Moho I think this is the point...I don't think Snowy does know the property path, he's crawling up the types, looking for a particular one without knowing the intermediaries. (there is no inheritance in the above example)

Comment: So what you're suggesting is he can start with any object of the above defined classes and want to find the related Class5 property?

Comment: @Moho, yeah using the visitor pattern you surely could. Although it would be sensible to have a limit of how deep to dive, in case the class and its recursive contained classes never had a property of the right type.

Comment: You would still know the structure since the classes are defined at compile time.  Or I'm totally confused haha.  These are c# classes right and not some DB table abstraction?

Comment: :-) well, yeah sure, if they are all his classes and he knows the design time composition, this then becomes a non-problem. But the question was, how do I programatically find the class, based on this structure.

Comment: These are POCOs, sourced from a remote web service. I do not have control over exactly where what I want, is.